# How to merge two numpy array's cells containing strings?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy, merge

I want to take a linear equation from users input and convert it to numpy array.

So i took user's input and used:

```
np.array(list(linear_eq))
```

As the result i get array that looks like this **['2' 'x' '-' '4' '=' '5']** 
but i want it to look like that  **['2x' '-4' '5']**. or even like **['2' '-4' '5']** 
 I am googling how to do this for half an hour now and i can't find an answer.
 Please explain clearly because i am new to programming. 
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show `linar_eq`, but I can guess it is:

```
In [9]: eq = "2x-4=5"
```

`list()` applied to a string breaks it up, producing a list of characters.

```
In [10]: list(eq)
Out[10]: ['2', 'x', '-', '4', '=', '5']
```

`np.array` on that list doesn't change things, and won't make grouping the characters any easier.  Stick with list operations.

The two proposed answers follow different 'rules'.  One looks like it takes the characters 2 by 2, but then drops the '='.  The other drops the 'x'.  Why?

```
['2x', '-4', '5']
['2', '-4', '5']
```

Your problem is not clearly specified.  But I suspect you'd be better off using the `regex` mechanism to split up the original string.  It isn't a merging problem.  It's more of a parsing one.

Comment: Your right, sorry. My main goal is to get to the 'naked' numbers and have easy access to it for a purpose of further calculations. I know nothing about regex yet, but i'm going to check it out. I'm grateful for quick feedback Thank you !!!